# What is the syntax in c to combine statements as a parameter

Tags: c, misra

I have an inkling there is an old nasty way to get a function run as a parameter is calculated, but sine I do not know what it is called I cannot search out the rules.

An example

```
char dstr[20];
printf("a dynamic string %s\n", (prep_dstr(dstr),dstr));
```

The idea is that the "()" will return the address dstr after having executed the prep_dstr function.

I know it is ugly and I could just do it on the line before - but it is complicated...

#

Ok - in answer to the pleading not to do it.

I am actually doing a MISRA cleanup on some existing code (not mine don't shoot me), currently the 'prep_dstr' function takes a buffer modifies it (without regard to the length of the buffer) and returns the pointer it was passed as a parameter.

I like to take a small step - test then another small step.

So - a slightly less nasty approach than returning a pointer with no clue about its persistence is to stop the function returning a pointer and use the comma operator (after making sure it does not romp off the end of the buffer).

That gets the MISRA error count down, when it all still works and the MISRA errors are gone I will try to get around to elegance - perhaps the year after next :).

Comment: Why not just do it on the line before?

Comment: But that should work, shouldn't it? With the `,` returning the result of the last expression.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You have the correct syntax (though I wouldn't advise using it) in the question.

Comment: The "what its called" and "why it works" are closely related: [**operator precedence**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Your `()` is considerably higher up the food chain than the comma operator, in fact they're on opposite ends of the operator precedence galaxy.

Comment: MISRA-C bans the comma operator. The sane and MISRA-compatible way to rewrite the code is: `prep_dstr(dstr); printf("a dynamic string %s\n", dstr);`. Also, MISRA bans the use of stdio.h in production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the syntax you use will work for your purpose.

However, please consider writing clean and readable code. For instance,

```
char buffer[20];

char *destination = prepare_destination_string(buffer);

printf("a dynamic string %s\n", destination);
```

Everything can be cleanly named & understood, and intended behaviour easy to infer. You could even omit certain parts if you so would, like `destination`, or perform easier error checking.

Answer (score 3):

Comma operator has the appropriate precedence and, besides, it gives a **sequence point**, that is, it defines a point in the execution flow of the program where all the previous side effects are resolved.
So, whatever your function `prep_dstr()` does to the string `dstr`, it's completely performed before the comma operator is reached.

On the other hand, comma operator gives an expression whose value is the rightest operand.

The following examples give you the value `dstr`, as you want:

```
   5+3, prep_dstr(dstr), sqrt(25.0), dstr;
   a+b-c, NULL, dstr;
   (prep_dstr(dstr), dstr);
```

Of course, such expression can be used wherever you need the string `dstr`.

Theerefore, **the syntax you employed in the question, then, it does the job perfectly.**

Since you are open to play with the syntax, there is another possibility you can use.
By taking in account that the function `printf()` is a function, it is, in particular, an expression.
In this way, it can be put in a comma expression:

```
  prep_dstr(dstr), printf("Show me the string: %s\n", dstr);
```

It seems that every body is telling you that "don't write code in this way and so and so...".
This kind of religious advices in the programming style are overestimated.
If you need to do something, just do it.

One of the principles of C says: "Don't prevent the programmer of doing what have be done."

However, whatever you do, try to write readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Your inkling and your code are both correct. That said, please don't do this. Putting `prep_dstr` on its own line makes it much easier to reason about what happens and when.

What you're thinking of is the comma operator. In a context where the comma doesn't already have another meaning (such as separating function arguments), the expression `a, b` has the value of `b`, but evaluates `a` first. The extra parentheses in your code cause the comma to be interpreted this way, rather than as a function argument separator.